# Nested states logic and difference between <ui-view> - ui-router and <router-outlet> - router module directives

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

Short-hand routs definition for ui-router in angularjs: 
`{
  state:'index',
  url:'',
  controller:IndexController,
  templateUrl:'/index.html'
 },`
`{
  state:'index.child',
  url:'/child',
  controller:ChildController,
  template:'<p>Child state</p>'
 }`
**/index.html**
`<div ui-view>some content<a ui-sref='index.child'>go to child</a></div>`

When user click's by link - all html contnent between ui-view open/closed tags are changed to child state content

All i want, represent the same logic for angular 2 **children** routes
my router definition for angular2:
`{
   path:'',
   component: IndexComponent,
   children:[
              {
                path:'child',
                component:ChildComponent
              }
            ]
 }`

**IndexComponent**
`@Component({
selector: 'index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})`
**index.component.html**
`<a routerLink="child">go to child</a>`
`<router-outlet>`
`<div>some content</div>`
`</router-outlet>`
**ChildComponent**
`@Component({
selector: 'child',
  template: '<div>child state</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})`

When clicked by router link - i got this result: 
`<a routerLink="child">go to child</a>`
`<router-outlet>`
`<div>some content</div><div>child state</div>`
`</router-outlet>`
But i want next result:
`<a routerLink="child">go to child</a>`
`<router-outlet>`
`<div>child state</div>`
`</router-outlet>`
Router-outlet didnt replace content as ui-router did, also it can be cured by making *not nested states*, but for some reasons i want this feature in nested state. Any advises?

Answer (score 0):

Using something like this should work:

```
{
   path:'',
   component: IndexComponent,
   children:[
          {
            path: '',
            component:DefaultChildComponent
          },
          {
            path:'child',
            component:ChildComponent
          }
    ]
 }
```

Where `DefaultChildComponent` would have `<div>some content</div>` as its template.

The content will never be placed inside the router-outlet. Always next to it.